# Why do the margins of the p tag disappear when placed in a td?

Tags: html, css

I have placed a `p` tag in a `td`, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 16px;"><p>Hello</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The default margins have disappeared from the `p` tag. Why is this the case and how can I get back the default `p` tag margins?

I thought it was something to do with the `font-size` not cascading as the `p` tags margins are `em` based, but that didn't help.

I don't want to directly add margins to the `p` tag, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a doctype declaration to your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 16px;"><p>Hello</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without it, your page is displayed in quirks mode, where margins may behave unexpectedly, especially when it comes to tables. I'm not sure what exactly is happening here that causes your `p` to lose its margins when in your `td`, but I do know that it only occurs in quirks mode.

Comment: Aaaah! I can't believe I didn't even consider that! Thanks Bolt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by disappearing, but you can just target your `p`s generally, and pad them up a bit:

```
​td > p
{
  padding:15px;       
}​
```

If you need to, you can make the selector stricter.

Comment: This will work too - putting an explicit margin in your stylesheet will override the browser's default. But it's still definitely a quirk!

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for it:

1. Is this problem only in IE? It could be a problem with quirks mode so would be better to add doctype as mentioned by BoltClock
2. If it is reproducible in FF as well then enable 'Show User Agent CSS' in [Side panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel) in Style tab in Firebug. Then you can check which CSS is overriding default CSS provided by browser. There could be some CSS like

   ```
   table p {
      margin: 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: This occurs in all browsers, and is indeed an effect of quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each

element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties).

```
           td p 
              {
               margin:0px;
              }
```